# Android: enable Copy from LinearLayout

Tags: android, copy, android-linearlayout, clipboard

I have linearlayout with lot of Textviews, I need to enable select/copy to clipboard.

I don't want to copy only one textview, instead i need to select more than one textview in the same time to copy.

Thanks to help.

Atef

Comment: You wan't the String inside the TextView?

Comment: Sure, but I want to copy for example 3 textviews in the same time.

Comment: You wan't that every time the user press on TextView to add it text to some array of Strings?

Comment: No, I want to enable the user to select from more than one text view, I managed to make it for one text view by setTextIsSelectable(true);, but with this i can copy only from one text view, I can't copy from two text views in the same time, ( i can't select from two text views with one selection)

Comment: This could be good direction to success:http://stackoverflow.com/a/6179365/3332634

Comment: this is the same, android:textIsSelectable="true" allow user to copy from only one text view