# Selection not working for spanned text (Background span) in Android EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-styles

I am trying to select a word which has background span by double clicking but the word is not selected.

But if I do programmatically using `setSelection(start,end)` selection works. Double click and Long press not working for selection

I used LinkMovementMethod in my editText.

Thanks

Comment: please check out my answer

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried with attribute `textIsSelectable`?

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/deviceIdTV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:text="" />
```

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/8969000/619673

However I used to use `LinkMovementMethod` to make text clickable on i.e url or to scroll textView.