# How to get start and end index of selected text in TextView?

Tags: android, textview, highlight

I want to highlight selected text in android textview.Can anyone tell me the possibility to get the start and end index of the selected text in android textview.

I use the following TextView for selecting a text.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:bufferType="spannable"
     />
```

To highlight specifix string I use following code.How can I get start and end index of selected text.

```
    SpannableString str = new SpannableString("Highlighted. Not highlighted.");
    str.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW), 0, 11, 0);
    textView.setText(str);
```

Comment: how would someone select text from a textview. please explain elaborately.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025818/select-copy-text-in-a-textview/6179365

Comment: I don't know people putting down vote without understanding or answering my question.They must add comment without putting down vote.

Comment: @DanieleD. My question is different from the suggested answer by you.

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you are looking for

```
    int start = textView.getSelectionStart();
    int end = textView.getSelectionEnd();
```

sample code:

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ClipboardManager cm = (ClipboardManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        cm.setText(textView.getText());
        int start = textView.getSelectionStart();
        int end = textView.getSelectionEnd();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Copied to clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
  });
```

Comment: Please let me try your answer.I don't know this answer will return selected text's start and end index of large text.Thanks for your answer.