# Unable to select TextView inside a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview

I am trying to select text from a TextView which is present inside a fragment.
This is the XML for my TextView.
The textIsSelectable, focusable, enabled and longclickable properties are all set to true according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37116712/6513036).

```
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/post_text_recycle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/post_divider"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:autoLink="web"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:text="@string/stall_user"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
                    android:textIsSelectable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:enabled="true"
                    android:longClickable="true"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

I have also programatically set the following in my Fragment activity:

```
text.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

If it helps, I am fetching data from a Bundle passed through the Activity that holds the fragment, then I am setting the TextView using:

```
text.setText(Html.fromHtml(data.getString("text")));
text.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

I am still unable to select the text. I read in some Stack Overflow post that setting width/height to "wrap_content" allows you to select the text (some old Android bug I guess). This trick has worked for my recyclerview TextView in another activity. Doesn't seem to work here.

Thanks for your help!

Edit:
Here is the entire Fragment layout code as requested:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.myapp.www.ViewFragments.OriginalPostFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/hide_toggle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="#eeeeee"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:elevation="6dp"
                />

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/detail_wrapper"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                android:paddingBottom="48dp"
                cardview:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                cardview:cardElevation="4dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/user_image_recycle"
                        android:layout_width="60dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/post_type_recycle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/user_image_recycle"
                        android:textStyle="italic" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/post_title_recycle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/post_type_recycle"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/user_image_recycle"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/user_name_recycle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/post_title_recycle"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/user_image_recycle"
                        android:textColor="#0094BD"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/post_divider"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/user_image_recycle"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/black" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/post_text_recycle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/post_divider"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:autoLink="web"
                        android:fontFamily="serif"
                        android:text="@string/stall_user"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
                        android:textIsSelectable="true"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:enabled="true"
                        android:longClickable="true"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: can you also add the fragment layout?

Comment: @Signo Check now. I have added the entire fragment code

Comment: Too many nested view hierarchy is not so good for performance reason see link https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/optimizing-view-hierarchies

Comment: @nyulan Thanks for this link. I will try to reduce the hierarchy. Do you think the issue is because of the hierarchy though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is `descendantFocusability`. In Your `CardView` layout, you set `descendantFocusability` to `blocksDescendants`.
What it does it disable the focusability of the descendants, so Your `TextView` never get those focus events.
For more info see [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup).

To make it work just remove this line from `CardView`

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I had blocked descendants in another place because the view would scroll down automatically. It's not doing that here, so I guess it should be fine if I remove it. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi,  i have the same problem but havent got any android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" in my xml. Keep can't understant why I can't select