# How to select all text in AutoCompleteTextView Android

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

I want to select the full text when the `AutoCompleteTextView` is clicked,

I used `android:selectAllOnFocus="true"` but didnt work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select + copy text in a TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025818/select-copy-text-in-a-textview)

Comment: Check my answer it may help you..

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:longClickable="true"
```

this is for TextView but might work for AutoCompletTextView